# php track who use my image

Tags: php

I want track who used my image in php script. file list.

```
/var/www/html/1.jpg
/var/www/html/tracker.php
/var/www/html/.htacess
```

.htacess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ tracker.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

tracker.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($_GET['id'].'.jpg');//echo '<img src="'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg'">';
file_put_contents('log.txt',$_GET['id'].' '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' '.var_dump(apache_request_headers()));
?>
```

the log.txt has been created, but the image doesn't display in browser. where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['id'].'.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
file_put_contents('log.txt',$_GET['id'].' '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' '.var_dump(apache_request_headers()));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/function.imagejpeg.php) is the wrong function. Try this instead:

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['id'].'.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do any job top of the php file and then use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)  function

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need a download situation. Just want to track who use my image. example. if another site streal my image `<img src="http://exaple.com/1.jpg" />` i could track it's server ip and other information.

Comment: It just outputs the file. You are able to do anything before that function.

`header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
file_put_contents('log.txt',$_GET['id'].' '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' '.var_dump(apache_request_headers()));
readfile($file)`

Comment: thanks, I know file put contents could display image. I give the anwser marker to giberno, because hellcode said imagejpeg is the wrong function.  but i have tested, the marked anwser also could display image which use function `imagejpeg`.